# How to clear trails when drawing rectangles on an HMTL5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am currently working on an application where I draw a rectangle on a canvas. I can draw the rectangle perfectly but then when I try to change the movement of the mouse to make the rectangle smaller there are trails that are left behind. How do I clear these trails when I make the rectangle's size smaller? below is my JavaScript code that I used. Thanks in advance.

```
 function drawSquare() {
    // creating a square
    var w = lastX - startX;
    var h = lastY - startY;
    var offsetX = (w < 0) ? w : 0;
    var offsetY = (h < 0) ? h : 0;
    var width = Math.abs(w);
    var height = Math.abs(h);

    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(startX + offsetX, startY + offsetY, width, height);
    context.fillStyle = "gold";
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    context.stroke();
    canvas.style.cursor = "default";
}

function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
        y: e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop,
    };
}

function handleMouseDown(e) {

    // get mouse coordinates
    mouseX = parseInt(e.pageX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.pageY - offsetY);
    // set the starting drag position
    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;

    isDown = true;

    if (isChecBoxClicked == true) {
        mouseIsDown = 1;
        startX = lastX;
        startY = lastY;
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);

        startX = lastX = pos.x;
        startY = lastY = pos.y;

        drawSquare();

    }
    else {
        canvas.style.cursor = "default";
    }
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    // clear the dragging flag
    isDown = false;
    canvas.style.cursor = "default";
    // get mouse coordinates
    mouseX = parseInt(e.pageX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.pageY - offsetY);
    // set the starting drag position
    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;

    if (isChecBoxClicked == true)
    {
        canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";

        if (mouseIsDown !== 0) {
            mouseIsDown = 0;
            var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
            lastX = pos.x;
            lastY = pos.y;
            drawSquare();
        }
    }
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {

    // if we're not dragging, exit
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }

    //if (defaultval == 1) {
    //    return;
    //}

    if (isChecBoxClicked == true) {
        canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";

        if (mouseIsDown !== 0) {

            var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
            lastX = pos.x;
            lastY = pos.y;
            drawSquare();
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: A screenshot would likely be helpful.

Comment: ... and a http://jsfiddle.net would be even better.

Comment: @Teemu i will try and get the jsfiddle up and running.

Answer (score 1):

A canvas doesn't clear itself. At least not a 2D context, like you are using. If you keep drawing on it, the new graphics is placed on top of the old. You need to explicitly clear it:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: But this would clear the whole canvas, there might be something else drawn in the canvas, which should be left there.

Comment: you have the arguments in the wrong order; it's startx, starty, width, height, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect

Comment: Yes this does clear the whole canvas and that is a problem because there is an image currently loaded there of which it is the one that I draw the rects on top of that leave trails.

Comment: Then you would need to redraw the image too. There is actually no way to remove the rectangle without also removing the stuff behind. 2D context is not layered. You need to handle that in your code

Comment: If the image should ALWAYS be there, you could set it as background image of the canvas using CSS. It will then be shown, and you can draw on it, but will not be affected by clearRect

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to clear your canvas. If you are only drawing a square you will have to do that in the `drawSquare` function. If you are drawing multiple things you will have to do it in a higher function that redraws multiple things.

For clearing the whole canvas, you can use the following code:

```
context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );
```

There are also a lot of canvas libraries that will manage this for you and optimize the areas redrawn (they might only clear a part of the canvas, so there are less pixels redrawn)

Comment: I am drawing multiple squares on top of an image that is already loaded on the canvas. The only issue are the trails that are left behind when   changing the mouse position.

Comment: You will have to redraw the image and all the rectangles every time then. You can only remove or add things on the canvas, not edit. To edit you'll have to remove and readd.

Comment: @ Izzey I cannot set it as a background because I need to also zoom on the image and drag it.

Comment: @PhumlaniShabangu I would suggest using a library for drawing elements on the canvas. It will probably be a lot easier in the long run, and you won't run into redrawing issues like this.